# get several method's return values from a class in one statement

Tags: java

```
Item searchByPattern(String pat)
    {

         for(Iterator iter = items.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); )
        {
            Item item = (Item)iter.next();
             if ((xxxxxxxxxxxx).matches(".*"+pat+".*"))
             {
                return item;
             }
        }
    }
```

The above code is part of a class from my java program

```
public class Item 
{
    private String title;
    private int playingTime;
    private boolean gotIt;
    private String comment;

    /**
     * Initialise the fields of the item.
     */
    public Item(String theTitle, int time)
    {
        title = theTitle;
        playingTime = time;
        gotIt = true;
        comment = "";
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    /**
     * Enter a comment for this item.
     */
    public void setComment(String comment)
    {
        this.comment = comment;
    }

    /**
     * Return the comment for this item.
     */
    public String getComment()
    {
        return comment;
    }

    /**
     * Set the flag indicating whether we own this item.
     */
    public void setOwn(boolean ownIt)
    {
        gotIt = ownIt;
    }

    /**
     * Return information whether we own a copy of this item.
     */
    public boolean getOwn()
    {
        return gotIt;
    }

    public int getPlayingTime()
    {
        return playingTime;
    }

    /**
     * Print details about this item to the text terminal.
     */
    public void print()
    {
        System.out.println("Title: " + title);
        if(gotIt) {
            System.out.println("Got it: Yes");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Got it: No");
        }
        System.out.println("Playing time: " + playingTime);
        System.out.println("Comment: " + comment);
    }

}
```

I want to access all the methods that return values from `class Item` and once it matches the statement in `Item searchByPattern`, it will return the object.
I knew that I can do it by `or` operator like `item.getTitle().matches(".*"+pat+".*") ||item.getComment().matches(".*"+pat+".*")||.......` 
but is it possible to get the same result by using a method in (xxxxxxxxxx)?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't directly possible to do, however there are a few things you can try (from easiest to hard):

1. Just check all String type methods yourself in your code.
2. Add a special method in `Item` that does the match so `Item` class can decide itself when it matches.  Here again you will need to make check all Strings manually.
3. You could add a method to `Item` that returns all methods that return a String as functions:

Code:

```
  List<Supplier<String>> getAllStringMethods() {
      return Arrays.asList(this::getComment, this::getTitle);
  }
```

You can then use that to check all Strings one at a time by doing:

```
  boolean match = item.getAllStrings().stream()
            .map(Supplier::get)
            .anyMatch(s -> s.matches("pattern"));
```

4. You can use Reflection to inspect the `Item.class` to find all methods that take no parameters and return a `String`, and then `invoke` them one by one.  This is complicated and slow, and beyond the scope of this answer to explain further.